# Iterator category of std::move_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

Does it make sense that the `std::move_iterator` adaptor just inherits the iterator category of the template parameter Iterator type?

Because forward iterators requires that the reference type is of cv-`T&`, however, for forward iterator templates, the `std::move_iterator<It>::reference` will be an r-value reference to the Iterator's value type (with the reference qualifiers preserved).

Comment: Yes it does. The iterator category describes the capabilities of the iterator vis-a-vis movement along a sequence. That doesn't change, only the reference type changes.

Comment: @RichardHodges But when selecting an "appropiate overload" for any operation regarding its iterator category, that "overload" will make some assumptions about the valid uses of the iterator, which will be wrong for `std::move_iterator`s.

Comment: are you able to provide an example?

Comment: I see there has been an update of the definition of reference in c++17. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because forward iterators requires that the reference type is of cv-T&, however

Incorrect. The standard (C++17, N4659, [forward.iterators]/1.3) says:

> if `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T` ; if `X` is a constant iterator, `reference` is a reference to const `T`

Rvalue references are a "reference to `T`". Therefore, they qualify. If they meant to exclude rvalue references, the standard would have said "lvalue reference to `T`".

So it's perfectly valid for a ForwardIterator to return an rvalue reference.